# Edit a dot cookie from javascript

Tags: javascript, cookies

This is driving me crazy. I am setting a cookie with a SetCookie header sent from PHP, without a domain.

```
setcookie('test','val',0,null,null,false,false);
```

Then firefox ( and I suppose other browsers ) automatically picks up the domain and makes the cookie available to all sub-domains with the annoying `.domain.com`. However I want to edit that cookie from JavaScript, how is that possible?

If I put

```
document.cookie = 'test=val';
```

Then I get two cookies with the name of `test`, one with domain `domain.com` ( set from javascript ) and the other one `.domain.com` ( sent from php ). I am being even further more confused by the fact that `document.cookie` and the `Cookie` header itself contain *no information* that could help distinguish the two cookies!

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.cookie

Comment: What is a 'dot cookie' (in your title)?

Comment: @SteveWellens well this may not be the correct term, I don't really know how it's called, when the cookie domain starts with a dot to match all sub-domains

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put:

```
document.cookie = "test=val; domain=.domain.com";
```

in the Javascript. The default is for the domain to be the exact domain of the web page, you need to put `.domain.com` in explicitly to override it.

The `Set-Cookie:` header that came from PHP must have contained `domain=.domain.com`